# If let var - Unwrapping optional value

Tags: ios, swift

There is some ways to unwrap an optional value:

```
// 1st way
var str: String? = "Hello, playground"
if let strUnwrapped = str {
    // strUnwrapped is immutable
    println(strUnwrapped)
}

// 2nd way
var str: String? = "Hello, playground"
if var strUnwrapped = str {
    // strUnwrapped is mutable
    strUnwrapped = "Toldino"
    println(strUnwrapped)
}
```

But I recently test this following one...

```
// The strangest one
var str: String? = "Hello, playground"
if let var strUnwrapped = str {
    // strUnwrapped is mutabe
    strUnwrapped = "yolo"
    println(strUnwrapped)
}
```

Can you explain me why does it work ?
It is a bug or a functionality ?

**EDIT**

As [niñoscript](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1904287/ni%C3%B1oscript) said, it was a bug.

It is resolved in Swift 2.0, I tried it with the new version and it doesn't compile anymore.

Now Xcode throw this following error for "if let var"
[image: xcode error]

Comment: It apparently lets you use any two `if let let ...`, `if let var ...`, `if var let ...`, and  `if var var ...`.  The second `var` or `let` controls the mutability.  Looks like an odd non-reported syntax error to me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**This answer is only valid for Xcode 6, the bug was fixed in Xcode 7 as noted by the OP's edit and Paul Jarysta's answer**

In this case:

```
if let var strUnwrapped = str {}
```

**let var** works the same way as just **var**, so either it is a bug or it's just the same thing. But if you try the following simple code:

```
let var n = 3
```

It throws this error:

> 'var' cannot appear nested inside another 'var' or 'let' pattern

So we can safely assume that it is a bug. We should be good developers and report it!

Answer (score 3):

This problem was solved in xcode 7 ;-)

[image]